# Approximation of $u \in \mathrm{H}^1_0(\Omega)$ by a sequence whose gradient is smaller than that of $u$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation

I'm looking for some help about the following question

Let $u \in \mathrm{H}^1_0(\Omega)$ with $\nabla u \in \mathrm{L}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ stands for a regular bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (actually, $d=3$).

I want to show that there exists a sequence of test functions $(u_n)$ with $u_n \in  C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that :

- $u_n \rightarrow u \ \ $   in   $\ \ \mathrm{L}^1(\Omega)$
- $\Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^{\infty}(\Omega)} \lesssim \Vert \nabla u \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^{\infty}(\Omega)}$ for all $n$, with $\lesssim$ independant of $n$

I tried different regularization/truncature procedures but without success...
Any help is welcomed !

Comment: my feeling is it should work with mollification

Answer (score 3):

Let $u_\epsilon = \phi_\epsilon * u$ the the mollification of $u$ with the standard mollifier $\{\phi_\epsilon\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$. It is standard to show that $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and so in particular
$$
\|u_\epsilon - u\|_{L^1} \leq |\Omega|^{1/2}\|u_\epsilon - u\|_{L^1} \to 0.
$$
As for the $L^\infty$ bound, we have
$$
|\partial_{x_i}u_\epsilon(x)| \leq \int_\Omega |\partial_{x_i}u(y)|\phi_\epsilon(x - y)\, dy \leq \|\partial_{x_i}u(y)\|_{L^\infty}\|\phi\|_{L^1}  \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty}.
$$
This requires some extra explaining, actually, because this is only valid for $x \in \Omega_\epsilon = \{x \in \Omega | \text{dist}(x, \partial \Omega) < \epsilon\}$. However, since the result holds for $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary, it thus holds for any $x \in \bigcup_{\epsilon > 0}\Omega_\epsilon = \Omega$. Another way of justifying it might be using the extension theorem to extend $u$ to a function $\bar{u}$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|\bar{u}\|_{H^1} \leq C\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$, although I'm not sure if you'd get that $\nabla \bar{u}$ is in $L^\infty$ like you would need.

Comment: Ok, that's the kind of thing I've tried. But your $u_{\varepsilon}$ are not compactly supported in $\Omega$. Actually, if I set $$u_n = \zeta_n(x) (\rho_n \star \overline{u})(x)$$ where $\overline{u}=\mathbf{1}_{\Omega} u$ on $\mathbf{R}^3$, $\rho_n$ a standard mollifier and where $(\zeta_n)$ are cutoff functions associated to an increasing exhaustion of the open set $\Omega$ by compact sets, with $\Vert \zeta_n \Vert_{\infty} \lesssim 1$ and $\Vert \nabla \zeta_n \Vert_{\infty} \lesssim 1$, it should work thanks to Poincaré inequality. But I'm not sure that I can find such a cutoff...

Comment: The main problem is that it seems to be hard a priori to control uniformly in $n$ the quantities $\Vert \zeta_n \Vert_{\infty}$ and $\Vert \nabla \zeta_n \Vert_{\infty}$...

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're totally right. Hm. Yeah the problem I think is that you can't get the gradient of such $\zeta_n$ bounded uniformly (at least if you want it to be 1 on a big subset of $\Omega$ but still compactly supported).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the function $u$ is Lipschitz on $\Omega$. For $\varepsilon > 0$, we consider the shrinkage
$$
u_\varepsilon(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(u(x)) \, \max\{0, |u(x)| - \varepsilon\}.$$
This function has the following properties:

- $u_\varepsilon \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $|\nabla u_\varepsilon(x)| \le |\nabla u(x)|$
- $u_\varepsilon \to u$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$
- $u_\varepsilon$ is compactly supported in $\Omega$ (since $u$ is Lipschitz).

[Feel free to comment if you need help w.r.t. any of these statements]

Now, (as in the answer by Chris) we can mollify $u_{\delta,\varepsilon} = \phi_\delta * u_\varepsilon$. For a suitable coupling of $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$, this sequence has the desired properties.

Comment: Could you clarify the third point? I do not see how being Lipschitz implies compactness of the support of $u$.

Comment: Since $u$ is Lipschitz and in $H_0^1$, $u$ is zero on the boundary. But if it is zero on the boundary then $|u(x)|-\epsilon$ is strictly negative close to the boundary. Hence $\max\{0,|u(x)|-\epsilon\}$ is zero close to the boundary.